# Merge columns of coordinates and create new sequence

Tags: r

I have to following data frame.

```
    x1     x2          x3
    0   58.33546    15.14554
    0   58.33604    15.14571
    0   58.33645    15.14581
    0   58.33681    15.14591
    0   58.33722    15.14600
    0   58.33810    15.14604
    0   58.33900    15.14599
    0   58.33966    15.14578
```

Consisting of long and lat, each pair belongs to a string (0,1,3,4 and so on, only the string 0 is displayed above).

I would like to first construct a new column with the pairs (x2,x3). How do I do that?

The coordinates above corresponding to 0 is actually a journey (say X), if there is another journey (Y) whose first coordinate is the same as X last, I would like to merge the sequence X and Y coordinates together and call that journey X (the continuation of X simply).

My data set is called data, for some reason merging them together wont work with

```
data[, x4 := paste(data$x2, data$x3)]
```

This will create a new column, only displaying x2?

Comment: Given your syntax, are you using `data.table`?

Comment: You don't need the `data$` part.. Try `data[, x4 := paste(x2,x3)]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really accustomed to the data.table syntax, but this would definitely work:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(0,0), x2 = c(58.33546, 58.33604), x3 =  c(15.14554, 15.14571))

data$x4 <- paste(data$x2, data$x3, sep = ",")
```